# How to create forms with MUI (material ui)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hiho,

I want to use mui in my current react project. Is there a different/better way to create forms than the following example?:

```js
    const [companyName, setCompanyName] = useState<string>("");
    const [companyNameError, setCompanyNameError] = useState<boolean>(false);
    const changeName = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        if(event.target.value === "") {
            setCompanyNameError(true);
        } else {
            setCompanyNameError(false);
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        setCompanyName(event.target.value);
    }

    const anyInputFieldEmpty = () => {
        var result = false;
   
        if(companyName === "") {
            setCompanyNameError(true);
            result = true;
        } else {
            setCompanyNameError(false);
        }
        
        // add the same check for all other fields. My real code has multiple input fields

        return result;
    }

    const resetFields = () => {
        setCompanyName("");
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <TextField
                required
                fullWidth
                label="Company Name"
                margin="dense"
                name="companyName"
                value={companyName}
                onChange={changeName}
                helperText={companyNameError ? "Company name is not allowed to be empty!" : ""}
                error={companyNameError}
            />

            <Button
                sx={{ alignSelf: 'center', }}
                variant="contained"
                onClick={() => {
                    if(!anyInputFieldEmpty()) {
                        onSubmitClick(); // some function from somewhere else, which triggers logic
                        resetFields(); // This form is in a popover. The values should be resetted before the user open it again.
                    }
                }}
            >
                Create
            </Button>
        </div>);
```

It feels wrong to do the validation this way if I use multiple textfields (up to 9). Its a lot of boilerplate code and if I add further validation rules (for example a minimum character count) it goes crazy.

Is this the right way to achive my goal?

T

Answer (score 3):

I think you should check the [Formik](https://formik.org/docs/examples/with-material-ui) for hook-based validation and [jsonforms](https://jsonforms.io/docs/integrations/react), [react-declarative](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-declarative) from json-schema based view creation

> Less code solutions is better on production, but for a learning reason it better to write real code based on hooks, contexts or redux reducers

```
import { useState } from "react";

import { One, FieldType } from "react-declarative";

const fields = [
  {
    type: FieldType.Text,
    title: "First name",
    defaultValue: "Peter",
    name: "firstName"
  },
  {
    type: FieldType.Text,
    title: "Age",
    isInvalid: ({ age }) => {
      if (age.length === 0) {
        return "Please type your age";
      } else if (parseInt(age) === 0) {
        return "Age must be greater than zero";
      }
    },
    inputFormatterTemplate: "000",
    inputFormatterAllowed: /^[0-9]/,
    name: "age"
  }
];

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const handleChange = (data) => setData(data);

  return (
    <>
      <One fields={fields} onChange={handleChange} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: screenshot]

An example project could be found [on this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-declarative-one-yjbjto?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Okay thank you for the answere (others too). But if I use these form elements my frontend looks different? Or is there a way to get the same appearance as the mui elements? And are there different input elements too? Something like dropdown menus or date pickers? I think it would be look strange to use elements from mui and formik mixed? –

Comment: @TimTa Formik is a state manager which can be used with MUI. It has not any custom fields or date pickers itself

Comment: @TimTa The 'react-declarative' is using MUI as a backend. The 'jsonform' has MUI rendering engine. So forms created by this tools will look native with MUI.

Comment: Will not recommend json-forms. It requires more schema related data and also handling dependencies between fields can get quite complex.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned. Formik and Yup works great for validation. Formik also provides a way to easily disable your submit buttons. Here is a codesandbox : https://codesandbox.io/s/long-butterfly-seogsw?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Okay thank you for the answere (others too). But if I use these form elements my frontend looks different? Or is there a way to get the same appearance as the mui elements? And are there different input elements too? Something like dropdown menus or date pickers? I think it would be look strange to use elements from mui and formik mixed? –

Comment: Formik is a library to handle your form. There are no elements . The elements you're seeing in the example are from MUI. I changed the variant in the example code I posted

Answer (score 1):

MUI does not have a native form validator
i recommend using react-hook-form + yup it's pretty simple and has a lot of tutorials

https://react-hook-form.com/get-started

EXEMPLE

TextFieldComponent

```
import { OutlinedTextFieldProps } from '@mui/material';
import React from 'react';
import { Control, useController } from 'react-hook-form';
import { InputContainer, TextFieldStyled } from './text-field.styles';

export interface TextFieldProps extends OutlinedTextFieldProps {
  control: Control;
  helperText: string;
  name: string;
  defaultValue?: string;
  error?: boolean;
}
export const TextField: React.FC<TextFieldProps> = ({
  control,
  helperText,
  name,
  defaultValue,
  error,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const { field } = useController({
    name,
    control,
    defaultValue: defaultValue || ''
  });
  return (
    <InputContainer>
      <TextFieldStyled
        helperText={helperText}
        name={field.name}
        value={field.value}
        onChange={field.onChange}
        fullWidth
        error={error}
        {...rest}
      />
    </InputContainer>
  );
};
```

Styles

```
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const TextFieldStyled = styled(TextField)`
  .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
    background: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.background.paper};
  }
  .MuiInputLabel-root {
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.text.primary};
  }
`;

export const InputContainer = styled('div')`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
`;

export const InputIconStyled = styled('i')`
  text-align: center;
`;
```

Usage

```
// Validator
const validator = yup.object().shape({
  email: yup
    .string()
    .required(translate('contact.email.modal.email.required'))
    .email(translate('contact.email.modal.email.invalid')),
});


// HookForm
const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(validator)
});

// Compoenent
<TextField
          label="label"
          fullWidth
          placeholder="placeholder
          size="small"
          control={control}
          helperText={errors?.name?.message}
          error={!!errors?.name}
          name={'name'}
          variant={'outlined'}
        />
```

Comment: Okay thank you for the answere (others too). 
But if I use these form elements my frontend looks different?
Or is there a way to get the same appearance as the mui elements?

And are there different input elements too? Something like dropdown menus or date pickers? I think it would be look strange to use elements from mui and formik mixed?

Comment: I use MUI but I do my own styling on the components... I'll edit an example of mine

Comment: Okay thank you. Your answere distracted me a little bit. I understood you wrong. I thought I should use formik + yup instead of mui because mui does not have a validation option. 
Now I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use json to generate forms directly. Few examples:

- [data driven forms](https://www.data-driven-forms.org/)
- [mui-forms](https://mui-forms.vercel.app/)

You can use standard material design or ant UI components with above libraries. 
You can also add your own components.

If you have custom requirements that cannot be achieved using above, then you can use

- [react hook form](https://www.react-hook-form.com/)

  - good performance but grouping or layouting not supported out of the box.
- [react formik](https://formik.org/)

  - a popular library for react forms but grouping of layouting not supported out of the box.